# Eclipse auto-import Scanner class?

Tags: java, eclipse, java.util.scanner

I've been using Eclipse on a few computers recently, and since using it on my home computer, have found that it doesn't automatically import java.util.* or java.util.Scanner after declaring a Scanner class in my code.

In my code, I type something like:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
```

... and in the past, Eclipse would add the `import java.util.Scanner` or `import java.util.*` line above my class.

Any idea how I could get the program to do this for me? I know it's a very insignificant thing, but everything I learn about Eclipse or programming makes me a stronger programmer.

Comment: Does `Ctrl+Shift+O` help you?

Comment: Not sure but maybe this could help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6293475/organize-imports-automatically

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion guys - good alternative, but not quite the same as what my other computers were doing.

Comment: Related, possible duplicate [Can eclipse be configured to automatically fix missing Imports?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3982885/can-eclipse-be-configured-to-automatically-fix-missing-imports)

Answer (score 1):

Use the shortcut ctrl+shft+o in Eclipse. It automatically imports whatever classes needed and suggests you with possible imports if conflict occurs.

Comment: This is great help, thank you! The problem, however, is that the other computers I was working on (with the same Eclipse version) did it automatically, no CTRL+SHIFT+O necessary. This seemed pretty friendly and, as it required no input whatsoever, was easy. Any idea if this is a setting somewhere?