# Eclipse removes external imports after saving the java file

Tags: java, eclipse

I have imported a few external library imports in a java file.
After saving the file eclipse auto removes these imports.

Quick googling showed me results about [organizing imports](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3983201/5051731). But these are disabled in eclipse work-space.

How should I prevent this behavior?

Comment: This is probably save actions https://www.eclipse.org/pdt/help/html/save_actions.htm

Comment: Yeah. I checked. The checkbox is unchecked for this option

Comment: If this is the "organize import" option, only the unused import would be removed, not the external library. What version of eclipse are you using ?

Comment: @AxelH For eclipse, since it cannot actually map the external import, it identifies them as unused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was in fact inside **Save Actions**.

Although the `Perform the selected actions on save` was unchecked, these settings were enabled inside `Configure Project Specific Settings` and the corresponding project.

Answer (score 0):

If you convert your project into a Maven project, you can add your imports into the `pom.xml` file. 
 Thus all your external exports would now be considered as internal ones.
If you don't want to convert your project to Maven, you could Add External libraries to Eclispe.  [See here](http://www.oxfordmathcenter.com/drupal7/node/44)

Comment: That would work. But the project uses a ant file for build.